# How to get jqXHR object from script request that is loaded from <script> tag inside <head>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

jQuery's getScript() returns jqXHR object when a script is loaded.
Is there a way to get the jqXHR object when the script is loaded from script tag which is placed inside head tag?

```
function makeScript(url){    
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    //when this line is executed the script will be loaded by the browser
    //how to get the jqxhr object
    document.head.appendChild(script); 
}
```

Comment: No. The XHR is not saved with the appended script element, nor does the script being requested have any knowledge of the request being made

Comment: heres jquerys [getScript](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/test/data/jquery-1.9.1.js#L8355)

Comment: @BenG +1 for pointing me in right direction. I replaced `document.head.appendChild(script);` to $.get as mentioned in the link.

Comment: Found another problem, can't debug the script as script loaded with $.get does not show in the CDT sources tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because there isn't one. The browser handles everything natively.